# Cannot set the default option in select in angular2

Tags: angular2-forms

I am trying to select a default option in select. Below is my code

```
    <select [id]="index" class="form-control" (change)="onChange($event.target.selectedIndex,$event.target.value)" (focus)="onFocus($event.target.selectedIndex)">
        <option value="" [selected]="true" disabled="true">{{'rec.select' | translate}}</option>
        <option  *ngFor="let attributeType of attributeTypeValues" [disabled]="attributeType.disabled" [value]="attributeType.attrTypeNm" 
        [selected]="attributeType.attrTypeNm===attributeEditForm.controls['attrType'].value">
            {{attributeType.attrTypeDesc}}
        </option>
    </select>
```

I can see ng-reflect-selected as true. Yet nothing gets selected in UI.

The code works fine on first time load. But as the selection changes the changes are not reflected in UI. For example, if the form value is changed, then the selection condition changes and the same selected option does not get reflected in ui.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would use a [(ngModel)] approach in this situation:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <option *ngFor="let v of values" [ngValue]="v">{{v.name}}</option>
</select>
```

with the following in the controller:

```
values = [
    { id: 0, name: "Value0" },
    { id: 1, name: "Value1" },
    { id: 2, name: "Value2" },
    { id: 3, name: "Value3" },
  ];
selectedValue = this.values[0];
```

important is that the default selection needs to be the correct object instance than the one used in the value list. Another object instance even with the same properties and values won't do => object identity is checked.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way and fastest way would be to check if your *ngFor fresh new variable is equal to your logic in the [selected] : (example)

```
<select (change)="size($event.target.value)" class="size-option" name="size">
  <option *ngFor="let number of [14, 16, 18, 20, 22]" value="{{number}}" [selected]="number == 16">{{number}}</option>
</select>
```